# How to remove code from HTML string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a variable that has this string:

```
<DIV><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">[If the confirmation is active the subscriber will receive this email after succesfully confirming. If not, this will be the first and only email he will receive.]</SPAN></DIV>
<p align=center>
    <input class=fieldbox10 type = 'button' name = 'button' value = 'Close' onclick = "window.close()">
</p>
```

How do I remove the below string without worrying about spaces via Javascript (or jQuery)?

```
<p align=center>
    <input class=fieldbox10 type = 'button' name = 'button' value = 'Close' onclick = "window.close()">
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your var was `myString` you can do this:

```
var temp = $("<div />").append(myString);
temp.find('p:has(input[value=Close])').remove('p');
myString = temp.html();​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sn3ng/)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?

```
$(html).remove('p');
```

Comment: I may have more HTML appended before and after. Is there a way to zero in on that specific paragraph? I just want to get rid of the close button. Any way to do it by the onclick = "window.close()"?